# Crawl IFrame content of a weppage using java

Tags: java, html, iframe, web-crawler

I would like to crawl the IFrame content (dynamic content) of a webpage;

But as of now no crawlers *(tried with Aperture,Crawl4j)* support this; Result which I get is

---

```
      <iframe id="template_content_frame" src="/ee/mypage/default.htm" width="100%" frameborder="0" name="content_frame">
      </iframe>
```

---

So started with [Crawljax](http://crawljax.com/). Does this support crawling IFrame contents? I came over this [issue](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/issues/3); It seems the above issue is **Closed not Fixed**, So I had a doubt that Crawljax supports this or not;

Do any one have tried this earlier / have any new solution to crawl **dynamic content like IFrame** ?

Answer (score 1):

[Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/) is an open source enterprise web crawler that supports crawling of `frame` and `iframe` tags out of-the-box.  You can also add your own set of tags to be used to extract URLs (e.g., `frame.longdesc`, `video.src`, `form.action`, etc.).  You need no programming skills to use this crawler, but since you seem to know your Java, you can also plug your own URL-extraction logic if you prefer.

Once you get more familiar with this crawler, I suggest you look up the [HtmlLinkExtractor](http://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/latest/apidocs/com/norconex/collector/http/url/impl/HtmlLinkExtractor.html) class on the online javadoc for more URL-extracting options.

Comment: Hi Pascal. i Tried Norconex Http Collector. Just Executed Maven project 
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project norconex-collector-http: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: -1

Comment: Hello Bass.   Can you describe what's the full command you used?  Are you trying to build it or run it?  To run it, run it from the command prompt using the approach described here: http://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/getting-started

To run it from your IDE, launching the com.norconex.collector.http.HttpCollector with the proper command line arguments works too.